# Wrong Aspect Ratio on new Devuan installation

Tags: resolution

The aspect ratio is stretched horizontally on my new Devuan installation, and I'm looking for the easiest way to resolve it. So far I've tried xrandr --newmode, but I keep getting the error `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default.`

Here are some terminal outputs that might be useful:

````
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sumo [Radeon HD 6480G]

glxinfo | grep -i vendor 
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.

find /dev -group video
/dev/video0

xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       0.00* 
   800x600       61.00  
   904x768_60.00  59.94  
  1000x768_60.00 (0x27d) 62.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1000 start 1056 end 1152 total 1304 skew    0 clock  47.74KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.82Hz```

Those last two aspect ratios are ones that I added but can't seem to activate.
````